# Java script time compare with given time

Tags: javascript, time

Ok I cant get my head round this, ive looked at so many posts on SF but cant figure it out.
I need to campare server time with hardcorded time.

i have try this

```
            var breackfastCutOffTime    = "5:30";
            var lunchCutOffTime         = "10:00";
            var dinnerCutOffTime        = "17:00";


            var serverTime = currentDate.getHours()+ ":" + currentDate.getMinutes();              

            if(Date.parse(toDay) ==  Date.parse(selectedDate)){
                if(serverTime >= breackfastCutOffTime ){
                    document.getElementById("breakfast").disabled = true;
                }else if(serverTime >= lunchCutOffTime){
                    document.getElementById("lunch").disabled = true;
                }else if(serverTime >= dinnerCutOffTime){
                    document.getElementById("dinner").disabled = true;
                }           
            }
```

I know this cant compare because time are in text format.Some one pleace help me to compleate this.

Comment: make your cutofftimes date string instead like var breackfastCutOffTime = new Date(); breackfastCutOffTime.setHours(parseInt('05',10),parseInt('30',10),parseInt('00',10),0); then comparison will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Date Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

Below is your modified code. I have commented few lines. Modify according to your logic

[Fiddler link](http://jsfiddle.net/37qjv17L/)

```
//var breackfastCutOffTime    = "5:30";
var breackfastCutOffTime    = new Date();
breackfastCutOffTime.setHours(5);
breackfastCutOffTime.setMinutes(30);

//var lunchCutOffTime         = "10:00";
var lunchCutOffTime = new Date();
lunchCutOffTime.setHours(10);
lunchCutOffTime.setMinutes(00);

//var dinnerCutOffTime = "17:00";
var dinnerCutOffTime = new Date();
dinnerCutOffTime.setHours(17);
dinnerCutOffTime.setMinutes(00)

var serverTime = new Date();

//var serverTime = currentDate.getHours()+ ":" + currentDate.getMinutes();              

//if(Date.parse(toDay) ==  Date.parse(selectedDate)){
  if(serverTime >= breackfastCutOffTime ){
    console.log("breackfastCutOffTime");
    //document.getElementById("breakfast").disabled = true;
  }else if(serverTime >= lunchCutOffTime){
    //document.getElementById("lunch").disabled = true;
    console.log("lunchCutOffTime");
  }else if(serverTime >= dinnerCutOffTime){
    //document.getElementById("dinner").disabled = true;
    console.log("dinnerCutOffTime");
  }           
//}
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of converting the Date format to string i am creating new instance of the date for each cutoff time and setting desired time to that object.

Finally compare the date objects directly.

***Note:*** The Date objects are set according to your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which converts Time(hh:mm) in minutes(mm) only. Then you can compare two times and do your operations accordingly.

pseudocode:

```
function convert(string time) int {
  //split the time by ':'
  //convert the string hh,mm to int hour,mm
  //calculate total minutes 
  //return total  minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the breackfastCutOffTime,lunchCutOffTime and dinnerCutOffTime to the below function and it will return true if they are equal to or greater than current time.

```
function compareTime(timeToCompare) {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var tempDate = new Date();
            var timeToCompareArray = timeToCompare.split(":");
            tempDate.setHours(timeToCompareArray[0]);
            tempDate.setMinutes(timeToCompareArray[1]);
            if (tempDate >= currentDate) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```